# When changing a Custom User model in Django Admin a plain text field is used instead of the special password field?

Tags: python, django

In the [custom user with admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) docs, it mentions that if your custom user model extends `AbstractBaseUser` you need to add it to the admin manually.

I have done that in `admin.py` with:

```
from .models import User

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', )
```

However when I go and edit a user I get:

[image: Plain password field]

Instead of the usual password field:

[image: Special Password Field]

Answer (score 0):

The model is treated as a normal `ModelAdmin` class and hence does not have a special form that treats the `password` differently.

You can view the [built-in auth forms in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) for a [full implementation check the full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

You will need to create a custom User Change Form like:

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User
```

Then set that form as the form to use:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    )
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
```